# Ubuntu error: no candidate ver

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, package-management

Ok...so for some reason by Ubuntu 10.04 partition won't startup anymore. I'm not exactly sure what I did. I have the feeling that I accidentally removed some important packages. However, when I startup in Recovery Mode and select "dpkg: repair broken packages" I get this output:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*': No such file or directory

Reading Cache
Reading Package lists: Done
Reading State Information: Done
Reading State Information: Done
Reading State Information: Done
No candidate ver: libisc44
No candidate ver: readahead
No candidate ver: libdirectfb-1.0-0
No candidate ver: upstart-logd
No candidate ver: libparted1.8-10
No candidate ver: libflickrnet2.1.5-cil
No candidate ver: libicu38
No candidate ver: fast-user-switch-applet
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-generic
No candidate ver: libnm-util0
No candidate ver: libwebkit-1.0-1
No candidate ver: libopal3.6.1
No candidate ver: libbind9-40
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-common
No candidate ver: upstart-compat-sysv
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-13-generic
No candidate ver: chromium-browser
No candidate ver: libisc45
No candidate ver: belocs-locales-bin
No candidate ver: libxcb-xlib0
No candidate ver: libpoppler4
No candidate ver: libpulsecore9
No candidate ver: libpulsecore5
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-15-generic
No candidate ver: libntfs-3g49
No candidate ver: libisccfg40
No candidate ver: libavahi-core5
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.27-7-generic
No candidate ver: libparted1.8-9
No candidate ver: libmagickwand1
No candidate ver: libwvstreams4.4-base
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-14-generic
No candidate ver: libraw1394-8
No candidate ver: libdatrie0
No candidate ver: libboost-program-options1.35.0
No candidate ver: libgnomekbdui3
No candidate ver: libsgutils1
No candidate ver: libass1
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-15-generic
No candidate ver: libindicate1
No candidate ver: libgnomekbd3
No candidate ver: system-services
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-13-generic
No candidate ver: libmagick10
No candidate ver: libcolamd-3.2.0
No candidate ver: desktop-effects-kde
No candidate ver: picasa
No candidate ver: libgnome-desktop-2-7
No candidate ver: libntfs-3g28
No candidate ver: libxklavier12
No candidate ver: libgpod3
No candidate ver: libmagickcore1
No candidate ver: libffado0
No candidate ver: libzephyr3
No candidate ver: libuniconf4.4
No candidate ver: libmbca0
No candidate ver: liblwres40
No candidate ver: hotkey-setup
No candidate ver: libkrb53
No candidate ver: ttf-bitstream-vera
No candidate ver: libee12-2
No candidate ver: libopal-2.2
No candidate ver: songbird
No candidate ver: plib1.8.4c2
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.27-7-generic
No candidate ver: libpoppler3
No candidate ver: google-chrome-unstable
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-14-generic
No candidate ver: simgear1.0.0
No candidate ver: libpoppler-glib3
No candidate ver: mono-common
No candidate ver: libx264-65
No candidate ver: libwvstreams4.4-extras
No candidate ver: libdns43
No candidate ver: libnm-glib0
No candidate ver: libpt2.6.1
No candidate ver: libisccc40
No candidate ver: libdns45
No candidate ver: libisc44
No candidate ver: readahead
No candidate ver: libdirectfb-1.0-0
No candidate ver: upstart-logd
No candidate ver: libparted1.8-10
No candidate ver: libflickrnet2.1.5-cil
No candidate ver: libicu38
No candidate ver: fast-user-switch-applet
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-11-generic
No candidate ver: libnm-util0
No candidate ver: libwebkit-1.0-1
No candidate ver: libopal3.6.1
No candidate ver: libbind9-40
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-common
No candidate ver: upstart-compat-sysv
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-13-generic
No candidate ver: chromium-browser
No candidate ver: libisc45
No candidate ver: belocs-locales-bin
No candidate ver: libxcb-xlib0
No candidate ver: libpoppler4
No candidate ver: libpulsecore9
No candidate ver: lipulsecore5
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-15-generic
No candidate ver: libntfs-3g49
No candidate ver: libisccfg40
No candidate ver: libavahi-core5
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.27-7-generic
No candidate ver: libparted1.8-9
No candidate ver: libmagickwand1
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-14-generic
No candidate ver: libraw1394-8
No candidate ver: libdatrie0
No candidate ver: libboost-program-options1.35.0
No candidate ver: libgnomekbdui3
No candidate ver: libsgutils1
No candidate ver: libass1
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-15-generic
No candidate ver: libindicate1
No candidate ver: libgnomekbd3
No candidate ver: system-services
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-13-generic
No candidate ver: libmagick10
No candidate ver: libcolamd-3.2.0
No candidate ver: desktop-effects-kde
No candidate ver: picasa
No candidate ver: libgnome-desktop-2-7
No candidate ver: libntfs-3g28
No candidate ver: libxklavier12
No candidate ver: libgpod3
No candidate ver: libmagickcore1
No candidate ver: libffado0
No candidate ver: libzephyr3
No candidate ver: libuniconf4.4
No candidate ver: libmbca0
No candidate ver: liblwres40
No candidate ver: hotkey-setup
No candidate ver: libkrb53
No candidate ver: ttf-bitstream-vera
No candidate ver: libeel2-2
No candidate ver: libopal-2.2
No candidate ver: songbird
No candidate ver: plib1.8.4c2
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.27-7-generic
No candidate ver: libpoppler3
No candidate ver: google-chrome-unstable
No candidate ver: linux-image-2.6.28-11-generic
No candidate ver: linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-14-generic
No candidate ver: simgear1.0.0
No candidate ver: libpoppler-glib3
No candidate ver: mono-common
No candidate ver: libx264-65
No candidate ver: libwvstreams4.4-extras
No candidate ver: libdns43
No candidate ver: libnm-glib0
No candidate ver: libpt2.6.1
No candidate ver: libisccc40
No candidate ver: libdns45

Your system is up-to-date

There are no upgrades available for your system. The upgrade will now be canceled. 

Do you want to start the upgrade?

Continue [yN]   Details [d]
```

I'm assuming I'm missing each of those packages. However, when I try to install them, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libisc44
```

I get some response that this package is missing and/or it may be part of another package.

I'm not exactly sure what I should do. I don't want to reinstall ubuntu, since I have it dual booted with Windows Vista and I don't want to risk anything on the Windows partition.

What are your thoughts?

**Edit**: I've posted this on Ubuntu Forums and nobody ever responded so...yah

Comment: if you'd use the code sample markdown for that big huge error it wouldn't show as quite so long -- the code sample boxes get scrollbars if they're longer than a certain size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have deleted some system directories. Depending on the amount of the damage, you'll probably need to reinstall.

Just in case it was just that one directory, do:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
```

Comment: I think that I'm gonna reinstall. It'll be nice to have a clean installation.

Answer (score 1):

Having a dual boot doesn't prevent you from re-installing, it won't be any more risky than the initial install.

It sounds like you lost some important file, rm, being one of them. Or you path is screwed up.

Try running the command

```
rm
```

If it tell you that the command can't be found run this

```
 echo $PATH
```

and put the output in the comments

Comment: I'll do this and post the results as soon as I have time to play around with my ubuntu partition again...thanks for the tip.

Comment: the command "rm" was not found so I tried that "echo $PATH" and I got this:

/usr/loca/sbin:/user/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games